# Yahoo Finance Quotes Table Data Not Being Updated

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Getting some hours old data from yahoo.finance.quotes table.

It was working yesterday. But today queries just return 2 hours delay data, When I am calling same API via curl

Please note: When I am executing API directly in the browser, this is all fine
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22^IXIC%22%29&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys.
Its returning

```
<LastTradeWithTime>5:15pm - <b>4707.42</b></LastTradeWithTime><LastTradePriceOnly>4707.42</LastTradePriceOnly>
```

But when i am calling same via curl it returning:

```
<LastTradeWithTime>3:13pm - <b>4698.50</b></LastTradeWithTime><LastTradePriceOnly>4698.50</LastTradePriceOnly>
```

Is yahoo YQL broken?
Did something change that I need to accommodate?

Thanks

Comment: anyone can please help

Comment: You are not alone. My group is currently discussing the same issue. We'll get "clean" (read: current) data much of the time, but then slip back into a 2-hour hole. no answers yet, but at least now you know you're not the only one :).

Comment: Here's the GitHub issue link for the table: https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/issues/468. It looks like there are several other stackoverflow posts about it too. Some answers are saying that datatables.org went down temporarily.